# Finding an updated node Facebook template

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, express

So I've been searching around the web to find a good node.js Facebook template but all I can really find is this https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs. It's decent, but it uses express 2.4.6 and node 0.6.x. I want to be keeping up with standards and working in express 3.x and node 0.8.x, but if I update the `package.json` I can no longer use the dynamic helpers that come with heroku's template, mainly these functions:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  'host': function(req, res) {
    return req.headers['host'];
  },
  'scheme': function(req, res) {
    return req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http';
  },
  'url': function(req, res) {
    return function(path) {
      return app.dynamicViewHelpers.scheme(req, res) + app.dynamicViewHelpers.url_no_scheme(req, res)(path);
    }
  },
  'url_no_scheme': function(req, res) {
    return function(path) {
      return '://' + app.dynamicViewHelpers.host(req, res) + (path || '');
    }
  },
});
```

Does anyone know where I can find some up to date information?

Answer (score 3):

Hi I had the same problem, to get this working there are multiple required changes:

First you need to update the dependencies in the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"async":     "0.1.x",
"ejs":       "0.8.x",
"express":   "3.1.x",
"faceplate": "0.4.x"
},
```

Then do your 'npm install' to get your local stuff updated.

Next surgery is required in several places in the web.js.  For my setup, I needed to update the list of 'requires' at the top:

```
var async   = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var util    = require('util');
var http = require('http');
var path =require('path');
```

Then comment out the old (2.x) style express initialization at the top.  Then add a new 3.x compliant one:

```
var store  = new express.session.MemoryStore;
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
app.locals.pretty = true;
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'secret', store: store }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('faceplate').middleware({
    app_id: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    secret: process.env.FACEBOOK_SECRET,
    scope:  'user_likes,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags'
  }));

// fix dynamic helpers
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.host =  req.headers['host'];
    res.locals.scheme = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] || 'http';
    res.locals.url_no_scheme =  function(path) {
                  return '://' + res.locals.host + path;
                };
    res.locals.url =  function(path) {
          return res.locals.scheme + res.locals.url_no_scheme(path);
        };

    next();
});
});
```

Notice the prior block contains the fix for your original question.  Just add your own middleware that sets those variables/functions as res.locals.  At this point you can comment out the old 2.x `app.dynamicHelpers` block.

Add in a 3.x style initialization:

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port')
  + ":" + app.get('env'));
});
```

At this point the problem is 'solved' but it still doesn't quite work.  Apparently the latest API for faceplate (perhaps due to FB changes) has changed somewhat.  So you will get errors after authorizing the app then trying to render the page.  This is due to the signature of the `facebook.get` callbacks being incorrect in the `handle_facebook_request` function, as well as a change in the data passed to the callback.

So using friends as an example this:

```
...
function(cb) {
    // query 4 friends and send them to the socket for this socket id
    req.facebook.get('/me/friends', { limit: 4 }, function(friends) {
      req.friends = friends;
      cb();
    });
  },
...
```

Should be changed to this:

```
...
function(cb) {
    // query 4 friends and send them to the socket for this socket id
    req.facebook.get('/me/friends', { limit: 4 }, function(dummy,friends) {
      req.friends = friends.data;
      cb();
    });
  },
...
```

Repeat this for the photos and likes and you should be good.

Comment: I wish I had this post 72 hours ago. Steps to get Node working with Heroku: (1) download the sample app (2) update all of the packages to something resembling current versions (3) completely re-write the sample app.

Comment: Great work, thanks for sharing! The Heroku Facebook template is on GitHub (https://github.com/heroku/facebook-template-nodejs), in case you'd like to do a pull request with those updates.