# Heroku - Application Error, but no error in logs

Tags: facebook, node.js, heroku

I'm hacking away at a Facebook app on Heroku, using Node.js. When I go to the app myself, it works exactly as I expect. When I send another developer/tester to it, the standard Heroku "Application Error" message is displayed. When I check the logs, there isn't even a log that the developer made a GET request for the app page, let alone an error.

He tells me that the last thing he sees in his browser status bar is "waiting for .herokuapp.com", which implies that Facebook got to the app, but the logs don't support this theory.

Is there another method of seeing Heroku errors? Is there something I have to turn on in order to see more? A setting I have to modify to let this other guy use the app?

**Update:** Some more looking around led me to check the network traffic. He's getting a 503 Service Unavailable, followed by the error page. Still wondering why this happens on his machine, but not mine.

**Update:** Inserted some error-checking code into the handle_facebook_request method.

```
req.facebook.app(function(err, app) {
    if(err !== null) {
        var errorMessage = "Error getting app: " + util.inspect(err['error']);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    }
    // rest of req.facebook.me, and rendering code
}
```

This gives me an "Unsupported get request", of type "GraphMethodException" and code 100. So now I have something I can look into! I wish that Heroku had at least mentioned that the request had been tried.

Comment: What's different between the two machines?

Comment: I wish I could tell you - they likely have little in common except that they are both Windows. :) I got a reasonable error message out of the system by inserting some error checking into a place I didn't think I would have to. (See above). I suspect that the final answer will be a long series of steps.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar-sounding issue with the untouched Heroku for Facebook app using Node. If you have logged in (have the Facebook cookie) then the app takes a long time to respond and you eventually get the Heroku error message. If you clear the cookie (Herokuapp.com fbsm_xxxx) the page displays normally. I haven't been able to find what is going on, but the sample app Heroku Node app for Facebook seems broken to me.

Comment: The sample Node.js app for Heroku (as of this writing) is completely out of date. This SO question shows how to update your app a bit in order to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434500/finding-an-updated-node-facebook-template. A commenter there suggests updating the Git rep, which would be nice, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a new facebook app created with the support heroku / node.js.

After several attempts and tests I saw that I get the message "Unsupported get request", type "GraphMethodException" and the code 100, because my facebook app was with sandbox mode.

When I disabled the sandbox my application on heroku it worked fine.